# JavaScript array manipulation, making any index as variable to get value

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a multidimensional array in javascript, [jsfiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/brilliantcoder/xa9ymswz/1/)
please check the below code. Some thing like this working in php but not in javascript, is this possible in javascript.

```
<script>
    var mydata = {'test' : 'testing'};
    var mydata2 = {'test2' : mydata};
    var myvar = 'test2';
    // This one is working
    alert(mydata2.test2.test);
    // but this is not working
    alert(mydata2.myvar.test);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) for this:

```
 alert(mydata2[myvar].test);
 //           ^     ^
```

> #### Bracket notation
>
> ```
> get = object[property_name];
> object[property_name] = set;
> ```
>
> `property_name` is a string. The string does not have to be a valid identifier; it can have any value, e.g. "1foo", "!bar!", or even " " (a space).

```js
var mydata = { 'test': 'testing' },
    mydata2 = { 'test2': mydata },
    myvar = 'test2';

document.write(mydata2.test2.test + '<br>');
document.write(mydata2[myvar].test);
```